Tags for LLM functions
There are several tags related to LLM functionality:
ai
chatai
llm
llmfunction
openai

and maybe more that I've missed.
I propose they be made synonymous with the same tag, and I suggest the tag be called llm-functions.
The WRI guide's title is LLM-Related Functionality and the webpage's URL ends in LLMFunctions.html, which is the source of my suggestion. (I suggest the shorter version, because short but descriptive titles seem preferable for tags.)
What do community members think?

Update
I'm retagging manually, since there are not very many Q&As and I do not have the rep to suggest a new synonym. If someone can suggest a synononym or a mod can create one, that would be great.

Well, I'm trying to create/suggest the synonym, but the system is complaining that the existing tag llmfunction is too similar. I've edited those to change the tag. I suppose eventually the tag will be deleted, and then I may proceed.

Well, darn, I don't have enough rep to create a tag synonym.

I guess I'll retag them [tag:llm-functions] manually. Still, it would be nice to have synonyms so that new posts would automatically be retagged.

I noticed all the LLM and ChatGPT related questions “rising to surface”, many unanswered. FWIW, agree single tag and simple tag and concorfant with WL  would be ideal. I know nothing about LLM but thank you for effort as collating would be good resource for learning. :)
